# Building Codeigniter Custom Application (seeking Advice) NoSQL?

Tags: php, mongodb, codeigniter, mongodb-query, amazon-dynamodb

Recently I've worked with my Developer to build a Codeigniter application to track user clicks on some ad campaigns using PHP/MySQL. In the past, I had used other paid tools out there to accomplish this, though they lacked the customization of building your own. This is what led me to this journey. Currently everything is setup on a VPS (paying about $70/month through Knownhost), so I think it should be good enough for what I'm trying to accomplish.

That being said, after building the initial tool and finally putting it to the test, it's super slow (usually resulting in 404 error, or a stuck query). I did some research, and I've discovered a few of my limitations. Anytime I try to gather click data on 5000+ clicks, it super slow (not loading 90% of the time).

1). Everything is built using MySQL (vs. NoSQL) and using a relational database. Accessing the data like this seems to be resulting in super slow queries. MongoDB looks like a valid non-relational database solution that looks affordable.

2). I'm not using a Cloud Database system (i.e. Amazon DynamoDB or Amazon RDS).

**Next steps?**
The next thing I'm going to test is loading the application on AWS Elastic Beanstalk to see if this improves the speed. If not, I will be going back to the drawing board and finding a plan of attack to optimize the page load dilemma I'm encountering.

Question:

1). Of the 3 points above, which do you think is going to result in loading the data faster. Obviously, some of it comes down to the programmer's ability to minimize and write efficient code ;)

2). If this were you, which of these areas would you attack first (if any). And if none, what would you recommend?

Thanks in advance, everyone. I appreciate your advice.

Comment: this question, besides interesting, is most likely too broad for StackOverflow. I'd suggest to ask at Database Administrators https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Thanks Vickel, I will see if I can draw some engagement there. ;)